# Sticky buttons in Inline dialog region

Tags: oracle-apex

A site in one of my programs has an inline dialog region that pops up for inserting some data, the region contains an interactive report with some apex_item checkboxes and the user ticks off a bunch of rows. The interactive report contains a couple hundred rows so the user might scroll down for a bit.

The region also contains a bunch of buttons which do some various functions. But now my problem is that the buttons are above the IR and when you scroll down, they dissapear and you have to scroll back up. The users dont like this and have asked me to make the buttons sticky. But I have not found any way to do this so far.

I have tried putting the buttons in a static region with the template Button Container, but it looks like this doesent work in inline dialogues. I have tried moving the buttons around, I have tried googling for hours, but now I turn to SE if perhaps the community here has some ideas.

Im on APEX 19.2 in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to play around with the (undocumented) stickyWidget, or do something like this:

- Toggle on the "Auto Height" template option of the inline dialog region.
- Place your buttons in a subregion 1.
- Subregion 2 will be the IR. Under its Attributes, under Heading, set it to "Fixed to region" and set the "Maximum Report Height" to something like 500px.

In short, the IR's rows will have their own scroll view. You won't be scrolling the entire inline dialog, thus the buttons will stay in place.

Try it out [here](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/stefan-dobre/r/sticky-buttons-in-inline-dialog/home)